# How can i deal with JEST handles potentially keeping Jest from exiting when using node-ftech

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs

I have written all my tests and i am receiving the below error on node-fetch when i test although all my tests pass

```
Jest has detected the following 5 open handles potentially keeping Jest from exiting:
```

```
11 | describe('the vip rotating ips', () => {
     12 |   test('the VIP json url exists', async () => {
   > 13 |     await nodeFetch('https://go-vip.net/ip-ranges.json')
        |                    ^
     14 |       .then((r) => {
     15 |         expect(r.status).toBe(200);
     16 |       })
```

The whole test is

```
test('the VIP json url exists', async () => {
   await nodeFetch('https://go-vip.net/ip-ranges.json')
     .then((r) => {
       expect(r.status).toBe(200);
     })
     .catch((e) => {
       fail(e);
     });
 });
```

Ive sought out numerous stackoverlflow solutions and documents however none seem to either give me a full explanation of the issue not a solution that suits my case.

I believe it's something related to timeouts

Can someone explain to me the problem and help me deliver a solution.